# Invalid SNMP when migrating from Zabbix 2.4.5 to 3.0?

Tags: snmp, zabbix

I setup a new server for Zabbix 3.0 and I was able export the hosts from 2.4.5 and then import them into the new instance. But the SNMP OID that I used in 2.4.5 seems to be invalid in 3.0?

The error I'm receiving is....
INVALID SNMP OID: cannot parse expression

This is what I used. 
Type: SNMPv2 agent
Key: ifDescr
SNMP OID: IF-MIB::ifDescr
Exactly the same setup. 
Am I missing a piece somewhere?

Comment: What makes you think the OID is invalid? What error do you get?

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have added that. The error is: Invalid SNMP OID: Cannot parse expression.

Answer (score 1):

For imported templates and hosts you must manually change the LLD rule SNMP OID (the syntax changed) - see [this what's new entry](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/introduction/whatsnew300#multiple_oid_support_in_snmp_discovery).

If you would like to see the import process properly updating the syntax, please vote on [this bugreport](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-10758).

Comment: Thanks. I've been playing with this but it's still not working. So under host / discovery rule the SNMP OID should be something like
discovery[{IF-MIB::ifDescr}, ifDescr] ?

Comment: Not like that - if you only want ifDescr, more like discovery[{#IFDESCR}, IF-MIB::ifDescr] (but make sure to match the macro name to whatever is used in prototypes)

Comment: Thanks. That cleared the error but I still don't see what I used to have. All I want at the moment is inbound and outbound traffic. That's it. It does allow me to see incoming traffic on Template SNMP Interfaces: Incoming traffic on Interface{#SNMPVALUE} but I can't choose the interface. Do I change the SNMPVALUE to the interface?

Comment: So your prototypes use a different LLD macro. Match it in the LLD rule, possibly like this: discovery[{#SNMPVALUE}, IF-MIB::ifDescr] .